# Writing an image to a flash size resulted in loss of size

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive

After i wrote Linux Mint LiveCD image to my 16GB flash, the drive's partition shrunk to  14.9GB. Formatting doesn't help and although Disk management shows that partition doesn't take the whole space it still doesn't allow me to delete or resize it (those options are greyed out). How can I get my 1.1GB back?

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed much more convenient to work from GUI tool (it is simple even for beginners) like [`gparted`](www.gpated.org]. If you can install it then go for this, `sudo apt-get install gparted` or download it as .deb file and then `sudo dpkg -i file.deb`

Also you can do your partitioning stuff from another Live CD like Ubuntu or even from Gparted Live CD.

You could do it right now on your machine by `fdisk` but check this example out and believe me, you first want `gpared`:

Example:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help): p

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     9437183     4717568   83  Linux

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1

Command (m for help): p

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Command (m for help): n
Command action
   e   extended
   p   primary partition (1-4)
p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-10485759, default 2048):
Using default value 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-10485759, default 10485759):
Using default value 10485759

Command (m for help): p

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    10485759     5241856   83  Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

Again, it is critical that the new partition starts at the same block as the old. The Id should also match (83 for Linux systems). Be prepared to lose all your data at the slightest typo.

By now it should be apparent why people recommend using a live CD. ;-)

However, once the partition is resized (and the system rebooted, if necessary), it's a simple matter of running `resize2fs` on the file system, and you can do this even when it's mounted as the root partition.

Example:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```